# bulk upload parquet to Sql Server using apache spark

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark

How can we load 10 gb of folder having 64 parquet files into sql server in a faster way? We are using spring batch, with file size of 10, and use spark jdbc to push into db, but this approach takes almost 8 hours to complete. If we load all files at once, it gives OOM issue.

```
  inputDataset.write().format("jdbc")
    .option("url", "value")
    .option("driver", "value")
    .option("username", "value")
    .option("password", "value")
    .option("batchsize", "100000")
    .option("autocommit", "true")
    .option("dbtable", tableName)
    .mode("append").save();
```

We are using 56gb RAM, 6 virtual core server.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty decent speed for jdbc. does your target table have any indexes or is it just a heap?